# I'm 3 things in 1. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Do this to a crop
>    Do it with a cup 
>    Do it with your hand 
>    If you're feeling stuck
>
> Do it to your enemy 
>    If you're truly vicious 
>    Do it to their house and home 
>    If you are malicious!
>
> Get it from the sky 
>    Get it from the Doc.
>    Get them from the ocean 
>    Carefully, good luck!

This riddle has one answer, but really 3.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first paragraph refers to

> Raise
>  Raise a crop, raise your cup (a toast), raise your hand (to ask a question if you're 'stuck')

Second paragraph is

> Raze (to level or destroy) 
>  Destroy your enemy, level their house

third paragraph is

> Rays 
>  Sun rays from the sky, X-rays from the Doctor, Sting rays from the ocean (carefully!)

This riddle has one answer, but really 3.

> \ˈrāz\  (raise, raze, rays)

Comment: 18 minutes to solve. You people are ridiculous!